# Weird double-underline for links to answers in user profile

Tags: bug, css

I noticed some rather odd behavior when moving the cursor over links to answers displayed in my user profile:

[image]

I opened Firebug to see if I could determine exactly what was going on here. The cause of the problem was not immediately obvious but it turned out to be a typo.

Here are the HTML elements for one of the answer links:

```
<td title="..." class="answer-hyperlink">
    <a class="answer-hyperlink " href="...">
        How to set C++11 as my default compiler?
    </a>
</td>
```

Notice that both the `<td>` and the `<a>` use the `.answer-hyperlink` class. What exactly is in the declaration for this CSS class?

```
.question-hyperlink:hover, .answer-hyperlink:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So we've got a rule here that puts a dotted border along the bottom of both the `<td>` and the `<a>` when they are hovered over. But then how come this doesn't happen for the links in the question section?

Here's where things get fun. There's another CSS rule that *should* override that one:

```
.user-page .question-hyperlink:hover, .user-page answer-hyperlink:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

See the subtle bug in there? `answer_hyperlink` should probable be `.answer-hyperlink` (a class not an element). Once this typo is fixed, everything works as expected.